# Execute an adittional script before access a location in apache

Tags: php, apache

I want to run a script before locations specified in `<location>` ca be accessed :

```
<Location "/add-content">
 # Run /var/www/abc/custom-script.php first
 # Then continue to load the actual page
</Location>
```

I have many websites having this URL in my server, so this can't be done in application level.

Can I  do this in Apache?

Comment: have you talked to the apache team? they may help and you cannot be worse off.

Comment: Not sure about that but you may execute a script from `.htacess` before every request is dispatched and can detect the `url/path`.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to set a [handler](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/handler.html):

```
<Location "/add-content">
    # Run /var/www/abc/custom-script.php first
    # Then continue to load the actual page
    Action pre-script /var/www/abc/custom-script.php
    SetHandler pre-script
</Location>
```