# How to execute a script before returning a directory listing in Apache?

Tags: apache

With Apache how might one execute a server-side script (let's say a PHP script) when the URL is requested before returning the default directory listing (when `+Indexes` is enabled)?

I've tried the following [Action](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_actions.html#action) and [SetHandler](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#sethandler) directives as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22889239/execute-an-adittional-script-before-access-a-location-in-apache)

```
<Location "/test">
  Action pre-script "/scripts/access.php"
  SetHandler pre-script
</Location>
```

This executes the script perfectly when I make a request but the response from the executed script is returned to the client. I really want the directory index to be returned instead.

Is there any way to achieve this or am I barking up the wrong tree?